# Drawing arcs between edges in graphs

Tags: graph, graphviz

I'd like to be able to draw arcs between edges in graphs, as shown in the example below -- I'm using them to communicate information about the parameterizations of graphical models, and doing it by hand gets pretty old.

I've been using graphviz, which doesn't appear to supports that kind of annotation (if the answer confirming my fears at [Connecting arcs between lines in Dot (GraphViz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256455/connecting-arcs-between-lines-in-dot-graphviz) isn't correct, that would make my day -- I really do need proper arcs and not the workaround the answer offers.) Are there any libraries (such as the JUNG library for Java) or tools that would make this possible?

[image]

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider reading in the layouted text output from dot, rendering the graph yourself and adding your annotation automatically. That would at least save you the (considerable) effort of implementing a routing algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does seem to be the only route to a fully automated solution to my problem. Unfortunately, I'm not certain it'll work in my particular case, given the difficulty I expect I'd have in making my own rendering output suitable for polished documents.

Comment: Too bad that this feature is missing from GraphViz.  And/or trees are rather common is some areas of Computer Science.